# web service Php for login with android

Tags: php, android, web-services

I have this code to make login with my application android ,
    but I need to test with some value

```
    <?php

         require_once 'DB_Functions.php';
         $db = new DB_Functions();

          // json response array
          $response = array("error" => FALSE);



          // receiving the post params

          /*  $email = $_POST['email'];
       $password = $_POST['password'];*/



     $email ="bi@yahoo.fr";
    $password ="123456";

    // get the user by email and password
    $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email,$password);

     if ($user != false) {
        // use is found
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
        $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user is not found with the credentials
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }


    /*else {
     // required post params is missing
     $response["error"] = TRUE;
     $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters email or password is 
     missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
     }*/
     ?>
```

file `DB_Functions.php` is this

```
 <?php



           class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
        // connecting to database
        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {

    }

    /**
     * Storing new user
     * returns user details
     */
    public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
        $uuid = uniqid('', true);
        $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            return $user;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get user by email and password
     */
    public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            $stmt->close();

            // verifying user password
            $salt = $user['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                return $user;
            }
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check user is existed or not
     */
    public function isUserExisted($email) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT email from users WHERE email = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            // user not existed
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypting password
     * @param password
     * returns salt and encrypted password
     */
    public function hashSSHA($password) {

        $salt = sha1(rand());
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
        $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
        return $hash;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypting password
     * @param salt, password
     * returns hash string
     */
    public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

        $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

        return $hash;
    }

     }

    ?>
```

how to fix that 
the file DB_Connect Contains all informations about database name and password ... all thing are correctly
 but when i put 127.0.0.1/myproject/myfileLogin to test with this values 
 email:bi@yahoo.fr
 password :123456 
 he show me Login credentials are wrong. Please try again! in My data base I have These two
 email:bi@yahoo.fr
 password :123456

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you do var_dump($user) to check, what this line $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc(); is returning?

Comment: And return 'false' instead of NULL, incase of no-match

Comment: $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email,$password); Put print_r($user); and check what response is printing in the page.